# Add an image in email body using Python

Tags: python, image, email, outlook, win32com

I am using below code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'to address'
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
mail.Body = 'Message body'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>'# this field is optional
mail.Attachments.Add('C:\Users\MA299445\Downloads\screenshot.png')
mail.Send()
```

I am able to attach a file but I want a picture in the e-mail body.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<img>` HTML tag:

```
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s"/>' % encoded_image
```

And you can put the tag inside your HTML content.

Don't forget to import required modules:

```
import base64
```

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko it works if mail body format is in html

Comment: It does not work in the desktop version of Outlook where Word renders HTML messages.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: Does not seem to be true (it works fine) as of today (latest Outlook from Office365).

Comment: This worked for me after I replaced `image_file.getvalue()` with `image_file` where `image_file = open(file_name, 'rb').read()`

Answer (score 1):

Create an attachment and set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F`") using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`.

Your HTML body `(MailItem.HTMLBody` property) would then need to reference that image attachment through the cid:

```
<img src="cid:xyz"/>
```

where xyz is the value of the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property.

Look at an existing message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMessage button, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double click on an attachment to see its properties.

```
attachment = mail.Attachments.Add("C:\Users\MA299445\Downloads\screenshot.png")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1")
mail.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:MyId1""></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 1):

One step further to Dmitry's answer, I write a completed version to send out outlook email.

```
def outlook_attach_one_image_inline(mail, filePath, i) :
    attachment = mail.Attachments.Add( filePath )
    imageId = 'MyImage%d'%i
    attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", imageId)
    return "<br/><img src=""cid:" + imageId +">"

def outloook_attach_images_to_msg_inline(mail, images)     :
    i = 1
    htmlForImages = ''
    for f in images or []:
        if not f:
            continue
        htmlForImages += outlook_attach_one_image_inline(mail, f, i)
        i +=1
    return htmlForImages
    
def outloook_attach_files_msg(mail, files)     :
     for f in files or []:
        if not f:
            continue
        mail.Attachments.Add( f )

def  outlook_send_email_with_images_attachments  (to, subject, html_str, images, files, cc)  :
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = to.replace(',',';')
    if cc :
        cc2= cc.replace(',',';')
        mail.CC  = cc2
    mail.Subject = subject
    
    html_str=''  #more message here
    html_str += outloook_attach_images_to_msg_inline (mail, images)
    outloook_attach_files_msg (mail, files)
  
    mail.HTMLBody = html_str  
    mail.Send()
```