# Python how to insert images using win32com.client and outlook?

Tags: python, html, email, win32com

I'm trying to send html emails using win32com.client. Here's a sample code:

```
import win32com.client as win32  

mail = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application').CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'sample@sample.com'
mail.Subject = 'test'
mail.HTMLBody = html_pages

mail.Send()
```

My solution now is to upload the images to a server and insert the urls into html_pages. The drawback is that the images are not displayed when the server is down. Is there a way to send the images with the emails using win32com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that would be sending images as an attachment:

```
import win32com.client as win32  

mail = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application').CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'sample@sample.com'
mail.Subject = 'test'
mail.HTMLBody = html_pages

attachment  = '*path to your image*'
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
mail.Send()
```

Or you can put image in the html body:

```
import win32com.client as win32  

mail = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application').CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'sample@sample.com'
mail.Subject = 'test'
mail.HTMLBody = html_pages + <br><img src="path">

mail.Send()
```

Or if you want the image actually attached to the body and not being linked to a path, have a look here:

[I am not able to add an image in email body using python , I am able to add a picture as a attachment but i want a code to add image in mailbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544369/i-am-not-able-to-add-an-image-in-email-body-using-python-i-am-able-to-add-a-pi)